# How does Firebase's Firebase.on() work?

Tags: mobile, client, server, firebase

How does Firebase.on() work? It's suppose to "Listen for data changes at a particular location", according to https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html
,but how does the client know when to update itself? Is the client also a lightweight server that listens to the Firebase server or does the client automatically do an update every x seconds?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase client keeps a connection open to the server. Depending on where your app runs, this can either be a [web socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) or a so-called [long-polling](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling/) connection. Either of these ensures that the server can send new data to the client as soon as it is available.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the concept of a server holding a request from a client was foreign to me. The "long-polling" link was very informative. Do you think a someone new to server development & HTTP methods (just in the process of setting up AWS) be able to implement HTTP long polling easily?

Comment: Long-polling is pretty simple to get working: in your server-side page you just wait for data to become available.

Answer (score 0):

The client listens for changes on the server and you need to update the client data (your objects) in the event callback.

As a suggestion, this can be greatly simplified with [firesync](https://github.com/gngeorgiev/firesync).